# Route between two routers

Tags: cisco, router, lan, ping, networking

This is the topology I'm working with.

[image]

I'm able to ping from `VPC_LAN_A`to `VPC_LAN_B` and trying now to ping from those lans to `Router_2_Cisco`.

Here are the configurations for these 4 devices:

**VPC_LAN_A**:

```
ip 192.168.10.1/25 192.168.10.10
```

**VPC_LAN_B**:

```
ip 192.168.10.129/26 192.168.10.130
```

**Router_1_Mikrotik**:

```
ip address

add address=192.168.10.10/25 interface=ether1

add address=192.168.10.130/26 interface=ether2

ip route

add gateway=192.168.10.161
```

**Router_2_Cisco**:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0

ip address 192.168.10.161 255.255.255.252

no shutdown
```

I've looked for it on the internet and I know I have to do `routing between the two routers` but can't seem to find the right way to do it. 
Any explanation would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that routers are aware of interfaces to which they are connected.

https://geek-university.com/ccna/directly-connected-routes/

So if you want to ping `192.168.10.161` from `VPC_LAN_A`, then the following happens:

- `VPC_LAN_A` will send the packet to its default gateway, which is R1's `e0 interface`
- R1 will check packet's layer 3 and will see, that the dest address is 
  `192.168.10.161`
- now it will look to its routing table and will see that this address is directly connected to `interface e3`
- so it will send the packet to R2
- R2 receives this ICMP message and wants to ping back
- but R2 has no idea what's the next hop for `192.168.10.1` (`VPC_LAN_A`), so it drops the packet

in other words, R2 does not know how to reach `192.168.10.1 or 192.168.10.129.`

The simplest solution to this problem is to specify the next hop for these addresses on R2

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/floating-static-route/118263-technote-nexthop-00.html

The next hop for `192.168.10.1` or `192.168.10.129 i`s R1's e3 IP address.
This is called a static routing.

Another way of solving this problem is to use a dynamic routing protocol, like RIP or OSPF.

Hope this helps.